# $\int fg = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n g.$

Tags: functional-analysis, integration

From an old notebook of mine, I saw this unproved exercise in class:

> Let $f_n$ be a uniformly bounded sequence in $L^p$ ($1<p<\infty$) such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. in $L^p$. Then for all $g \in L^q$, $$\int fg = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n g.$$

How does one show this directly? I'm lost on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Let $|f_n(x)| \leq B$. Then $|f_n(x)g(x)| \leq B|g(x)|$ for all $x$. Also, $f_n(x)g(x) \to f(x)g(x)$ a.e. Now use the particular DCT.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: **Generalized** Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem